# Check if value exist in DBF database

Tags: vb.net, exists, dbf

I am trying to check if value "IAV-1419" exist in second column (`ColName`) in database named `PROMGL.DBF`.

I get this error : No value give for one or more required parameters

```
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

    Dim FilePath As String = "C:\"
    Dim DBF_File As String = "PROMGL"
    Dim ColName As String = "[NALOG,C,8]"
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & FilePath & _
    " ;Extended Properties=dBASE IV"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM PROMGL WHERE [NALOG,C,8] = @NAL")


    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAL", "IAV-1419")
    Using reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If reader.HasRows Then
            con.Close()
            Label6.Text = "EXIST"
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox1.Focus()

        Else
            Label6.Text = "DOESN'T EXIST"

        End If
    End Using
```

I am stuck here, if anyone could please check this code for me.

Comment: Not sure about it, but OleDb requires the parameters placeholders to be a question mark ?. You could try to change @NAL to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you sure that your connectionstring is correct????

```
Data Source=" & FilePath &
```

how connection string know the database where it point only to "C:\" i think is missing database name

Another personal suggestion make your code more simple to read in example :

```
    Dim FilePath As String = "C:\"
    Dim DBF_File As String = "PROMGL"
    Dim ColName As String = "[NALOG,C,8]"
    Using con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & FilePath & _
    " ;Extended Properties=dBASE IV")
        con.Open()
    Using  cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM PROMGL WHERE [NALOG,C,8] = @NAL", con
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAL", "IAV-1419")
            Using reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.HasRows Then
                    Label6.Text = "EXIST"
                    TextBox1.Text = ""
                    TextBox1.Focus()
                Else
                    Label6.Text = "DOESN'T EXIST"
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: File path is C:\PROMGL.dbf if I put that path in FilePath I get an error : "C:\PROMGL.dbf is not a valid path..."

Comment: you need to add to something like this C:\\PROMGL.dbf
Also put all into a try cath so you can go through your execption and see where is the issues.

Comment: With dBase the table name is the file name... so PROMGL will equate to PROMGL.dbf hence filepath C:\ is OK.

Comment: Check that column names and table names are same case as in DB. I'm not sure if dBase is case sensitive or not.

Comment: I never use dBase but you use filePath as C:\ then I assume that is C:\ directory

Comment: Use NALOG instead of NALOG,C,8

Comment: ok now i see then i want to pay attention to this : Data Source=" & FilePath" ;Extended Properties=dBASE IV")! Filepath now is only "C:\" to achive your goal you should nedd to change it into Data Source=" & FilePath & DBF_FILE" ;Extended Properties=dBASE IV") and it should work

In this manner you should have the right connection path however take care to try with "C:\yourfilename.ext" and also "C:\\youfilename.ext"

Comment: @Oleg... is the C,8 a formating instruction? and NALOG (TAX) is the column name?

Comment: I think that the only possible explanation is the implicit one given by @Oleg. The error message talks about a missing parameter. This means that the driver has found a name that doesn't exist as a column or table name, thus it considers that name a parameter's name. And that `C,8` seems to be suspect. Perhaps it means NALOG is Character field with 8 char length.

Comment: ok but the question is oledbconnection need a database to connect to and its cnn connectionstring i see only a directory (filepath= c:\") which could be the issue.If it has no reference to a database it should be an invalid parameter.OledDbConnection string expose Database Property taken from Datasource property. in this case c:\ checkedon microsoft guidline

Comment: PROMGL is table name and file name. 

@Steve NALOG,C,8 is exact name of column and C and 8 are character and field length. 

I don't think that connection with DBF is established and I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: @makemoney Putting filename after filepath results in error...is not valid path. Also I don't have a choice, I have to use DBF.

Comment: at this point i'm curiosu to understand how it work :) never used

Comment: @makemoney2010 think to the directory as the database and the single DBF as the tables. A DBF file contains only one table, you have many DBF for each table in your database. It will be less confusing if the poster choose a subfolder for its DBF files, but this is how DBF worked